# Why the use of MD simulations is less popular for the study of carbohydrates?

Tags: computational-chemistry, carbohydrates, molecular-dynamics

In classical all-atom MD simulations, the force fields for proteins, nucleic acids and lipids seem to be more well developed than carbohydrates. It seems to me that the use of MD simulations is not so popular for the study of carbohydrates. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: No reason that I know of. I would guess that there is less funding in that area... unfortunately money drives research interest.

Comment: Maybe because there are much more actively studied questions and structural variability with proteins (enzymes), nucleic acids and lipids than carbohydrates? I mean soaking starch in water is interesting and stuff, but carbohydrate macromolecules are generally static structural elements and energy careers, while proteins, nucleic acids, even lipid membranes have much more active, dynamic roles.

Comment: Might just be that the force fields for proteins, nucleic acids and lipids are more well developed than carbohydrates - force field generation is not straightforward and out side the experience (and interest) of your average (bio-)chemist.

Comment: I am not sure this is true (that it is less popular), and also wonder if either of the following apply: (1) one size fits all (finding a suitable set of ff  parameters for a general carbohydrate is not hard) or (2) just the opposite (describing any individual carbohydrate requires costly parameterizations of dihedrals, slowing down implementation)

Comment: Second, what Greg says, but there are [glycoproteins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycoprotein) though. Maybe it's just that they're aren't all that different. While in lipids that's mostly vdW and hydrophobic effect and DNA/RNA needs charge transfer, carbohydrates use h-bonds like proteins.